# Soundflower replacement on M1 Macs

Tags: mac, audio, apple-silicon

In the past, [Soundflower](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower) has been a great way to record audio generated by applications on my Mac. Soundflower's GitHub page indicates that it does not (yet?) support M1 Macs. In the absence of this great utility, how have M1 Mac users gone about recording computer audio?

Comment: They continue using their older macs? At least until Soundflower is updated...

Comment: Hmm, https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation? :-) https://www.rogueamoeba.com has several applications for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BlackHole is similar to Soundflower. Rogue Amoeba is better, but not free.

There's a discussion regarding Apple Silicon compatibility at
https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole/discussions/227

I've never tried it myself (prefer RA) but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: This is awesome. I knew Rogue Amoeba returned Soundflower to its original owner; I didn't realize they had updated products that do this! When you say Rogue Amoeba, do you mean Loopback or Audio Hijack?

Comment: Horses for courses, really. It depends what you need. SoundSource just for consumer output, Hijack can do some routing but isn't as comprehensive as Loopback. I tend to have SoundSource on machines for HTPC etc to hone my movie playback audio, but the 'pro' machines have both Hijack & Loopback… just in case.) afaik, they all have free trials. I'd definitely give them some hands-on to see which is most suitable for your needs. For simple 'app recording' including multiple simultaneous sources, Hijack might just be enough on its own. For more complex routing, Loopback .

Comment: I have recently started using BlackHole on Intel Macs and it works great! Look forward to trying it on M1 macs too.